# Alternative to PHP LDAP combo

Tags: php, ldap, web-hosting

I've checked with my current web host and they dont support LDAP in their PHP config because of security issues (!?) is there anything else i can do with PHP and my ldap server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it sounds like you are exposing your own LDAP server - but perhaps on a differnt host?

OR

You mean they don't provide a version of PHP compiled with LDAP support to act as a client.

A few thoughts:

1) "Security Issues" is an easy excuse for anything. That is not to say the LDAP libraires don't require certain security measures, but to avoid a technology altogether is not the most elegant solution.

So I would scrutinize your selection of provider.

2) However, you can, assuming some elevated access (root, sudo) just compile your own version of PHP with LDAP
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php

Comment: We have an SBS 2008 server in our office and i'm attempting to use PHP on our intranet to extract user info ie. contacts, etc from it. I was told to use LDAP with PHP but as i said my hosting provider does not support LDAP. So i'm at a loss

Comment: Have you considered install your own php on the SBS

Comment: Nope. At the moment, we have our intranet housed on our separate (from the sbs) web host. It was here i wanted to do the PHP-LDAP stuff...

Comment: if i cant do ANYTHING on the web host then yes, installing PHP on the server might be an option

Comment: Do you have any internal SysAdmins that have elevated access on any servers inside your intranet's firewall?  
It seems obscure for a hosting provider to tell you what you can and can not do on your own intranet.

Comment: I do apologise, by Intranet i sort of meant "internal web site", my fault!